# Parse LocalDataStore sorting doesn't work

Tags: java, android, sorting, parse-platform

When i am enabling the data store my query result is not sorted. The same query if i fetch from network i am able to get sorted order. I am using parse for Android SDK version Parse 1.5.1.

My code :

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> locBasedQuery = ParseQuery
            .getQuery(Constants.CLASS_MESSAGEOVERVIEW);
    locBasedQuery.fromLocalDatastore();

    locBasedQuery.whereWithinKilometers(Constants.MESSAGEOVERVIEW_LOCATION,
            new ParseGeoPoint(latitude, longitude), radius);

    if (sortingType == Constants.HOME_TAB_NEW) {
        locBasedQuery.orderByDescending(Constants.COLUMN_UPDATED_TIME);
    } else {                 locBasedQuery.orderByDescending(Constants.MESSAGEOVERVIEW_NOOFCOMMENTS);
    }

locBasedQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {


                }

            } );
```

Comment: Please add a tag to specify the programming language (e.g. Java) and also add the following information to your post: what service do you query (e.g. URL), what platform are you developing for (iOS, Android, ...), what does the result look (exactly) that you expect.